# swift How to cast from Int? to String

Tags: swift

In Swift, i cant cast Int to String by:

```
var iString:Int = 100
var strString = String(iString)
```

But my variable in Int? , there for error: `Cant invoke 'init' with type '@Ivalue Int?'`

Example

```
let myString : String = "42"
let x : Int? = myString.toInt()

if (x != null) {
    // Successfully converted String to Int
    //And how do can i convert x to string???
}
```

Comment: This no longer works in Swift 3

Comment: For `var strString = String(iString)` you are *creating* a new String from an Int. This is not the same as casting.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can use string interpolation.

```
let x = 100
let str = "\(x)"
```

if `x` is an optional you can use `optional binding`

```
var str = ""
if let v = x {
   str = "\(v)"
}
println(str)
```

if you are sure that `x` will never be `nil`, you can do a `forced unwrapping` on an `optional value`.

```
var str = "\(x!)"
```

In a single statement you can try this

```
let str = x != nil ? "\(x!)" : ""
```

Based on @RealMae's comment, you can further shorten this code using the `nil coalescing operator (??)`

```
let str = x ?? ""
```

Comment: Short version:  let str = x ?? ""

Comment: how would you do this in swift2?  shows Optional("100") for me as well @Sonrobby

Comment: @RealNmae Your comment: let str = x ?? "" will give an error if x is an Int or Int?. The default value must be the same time as x.

Answer (score 27):

I like to create small extensions for this:

```
extension Int {
    var stringValue:String {
        return "\(self)"
    }
}
```

This makes it possible to call optional ints, without having to unwrap and think about nil values:

```
var string = optionalInt?.stringValue
```

Comment: Thanks, The way i wanted to.

Comment: OP asked for Int? to string.
String interpolation produces a debug description for an optional value

Answer (score 27):

If you need a one-liner it can be achieved by:

```
let x: Int? = 10
x.flatMap { String($0) } // produces "10"
let y: Int? = nil
y.flatMap { String($0) } // produces nil
```

if you need a default value, you can simply go with

```
(y.flatMap { String($0) }) ?? ""
```

EDIT:

Even better without curly brackets:

```
y.flatMap(String.init)
```

[Apple's flatMap(_:) Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/1540500-flatmap)

Comment: Note that since `String.init` is not failable, you can use `map` instead of `flatMap`.

Answer (score 6):

Optional Int -> Optional String:

If `x: Int?` (or `Double?` - doesn't matter)

```
var s = x.map({String($0)})
```

This will return `String?`

To get a `String` you can use :

```
var t = s ?? ""
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps

```
var a = 50
var str = String(describing: a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Crude perhaps, but you could just do:

```
let int100 = 100
println(int100.description) //Prints 100
```

Answer (score 1):

Sonrobby, I believe that "Int?" means an optional int. Basically, by my understanding, needs to be unwrapped.

So doing the following works fine:

```
let y: Int? = 42
let c = String(y!)
```

That "!" unwraps the variable. Hope this helps!

As rakeshbs mentioned, make sure the variable won't be nill.

Answer (score 1):

You need to "unwrap" your optional in order to get to the real value inside of it [as described here](https://medium.com/@rrridges/swift-optionals-a10dcfd8aab5). You unwrap an option with "!". So, in your example, the code would be:

```
let myString : String = "42"
let x : Int? = myString.toInt()

if (x != null) {
    // Successfully converted String to Int
    // Convert x (an optional) to string by unwrapping
    let myNewString = String(x!)
}
```

Or within that conditional, you could use string interpolation:

```
let myNewString = "\(x!)" // does the same thing as String(x!)
```

Answer (score 1):

For preventing unsafe optional unwraps I use it like below as suggested by @AntiStrike12,

```
 if let theString = someVariableThatIsAnInt  {        
    theStringValue = String(theString!))
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Swift 3:

```
var iString:Int = 100
var strString = String(iString)
extension String {
    init(_ value:Int){/*Brings back String() casting which was removed in swift 3*/
        self.init(describing:value)
    }
}
```

This avoids littering your code with the verbose: `String(describing:iString)`

**Bonus:** Add similar init methods for commonly used types such as: `Bool`, `CGFloat` etc.

Comment: @Eric Aya: Why are you not supposed to cast variables with String()? You can use "\()" but Cognitively id argue that String(someVariable) is much cleaner. It's also how it's done in most other languages so it's familiar. Personally I use "\()" only within print calls. As it makes sense to use it there.

Comment: String(describing:4.0) and "\(4.0)" and 4.0.description is the same thing no? Every call rely on CustomStringConvertible, as long as your class implements CustomStringConvertible the result will be as expected.

Comment: Oops. Well, I should learn how to read. I was thinking about `String(reflecting:)` when I made my comments, which is unrelated to your answer. Apologies for the waste of time...

Comment: Didn't know String(reflecting:) existed. Could be use full for Encoding/Decoding classes to JSON etc. Thx

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to convert Int? to string

```
let myString : String = "42"
let x : Int? = myString.toInt()

let newString = "\(x ?? 0)"
print(newString)        // if x is nil then optional value will be "0"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want an empty string if it not set (nil)

```
extension Int? {
    var stringValue:String {
      return self == nil ? "" : "\(self!)"
    }
}
```