# Remove Optional and nil

Tags: json, swift

#### cellForRow

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) 
    -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = 
            tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "EventsCell") as? EventsCell 
            else { return UITableViewCell() }
        cell.homeLabel.text = events[indexPath.row].homeTeamName
        cell.awayLabel.text = events[indexPath.row].awayTeamName
        cell.homeGoalLbl.text = 
            String (describing: events[indexPath.row].result.goalsHomeTeam)
        cell.awayGoalLbl.text = 
            String (describing: events[indexPath.row].result.goalsAwayTeam)
        return cell
    }
```

#### Codables

```
class EventsFull: Codable {
    let fixtures: [EventsData]
    init(fixtures: [EventsData]) {
        self.fixtures = fixtures
    }
}

class ResultsData: Codable {
    let goalsHomeTeam: Int?
    let goalsAwayTeam: Int?
    init(goalsHomeTeam: Int,goalsAwayTeam: Int) {
        self.goalsHomeTeam = goalsHomeTeam
        self.goalsAwayTeam = goalsAwayTeam
    }
}

class EventsData: Codable {
    let date: String
    let status: String
    let matchday: Int
    let homeTeamName: String
    let awayTeamName: String
    let result: ResultsData
    let odds: Double?

    init(date: String, status: String, matchday: Int, homeTeamName: String, awayTeamName: String, result: ResultsData, odds: Double) {
        self.date = date
        self.status = status
        self.matchday = matchday
        self.homeTeamName = homeTeamName
        self.awayTeamName = awayTeamName
        self.result = result
        self.odds = odds  
    }
}
```

[image]

console:

```
downloaded

Optional(3)
Optional(2)
```

How to remove Optional from the view and how to "nil" does not appear?

Answer (score 3):

If we get `nil`, what string should appear in the goals labels? You need to specify that. Then you can write this:

```
let ifnil = "" // or whatever the desired string is
cell.homeGoalLbl.text = 
    events[indexPath.row].result.goalsHomeTeam.flatMap {String($0)} ?? ifnil
cell.awayGoalLbl.text = 
    events[indexPath.row].result.goalsAwayTeam.flatMap {String($0)} ?? ifnil
```

That will do both jobs at once — it eliminates both "Optional" and "nil" as possible label values.

[See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42960286/341994.]

Comment: i get error Cannot convert value of type 'Int?' to expected argument type 'String??' for goalsHomeTeam and goalsAwayTeam

Comment: @NenadSavic ok I think I fixed that.